# SIGINT was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++11, makefile, raspbian

**Background**

I am trying to build a sample REST api app for Rasbian running on Raspberry 3. I used `cpprestsdk`.

Sample contains the following header file:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

static std::condition_variable _condition;
static std::mutex _mutex;

namespace cfx {
    class InterruptHandler {
    public:
        static void hookSIGINT() {
            signal(SIGINT, handleUserInterrupt);        
        }

        static void handleUserInterrupt(int signal){
            if (signal == SIGINT) {
                std::cout << "SIGINT trapped ..." << '\n';
                _condition.notify_one();
            }
        }

        static void waitForUserInterrupt() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock { _mutex };
            _condition.wait(lock);
            std::cout << "user has signaled to interrup program..." << '\n';
            lock.unlock();
        }
    };
}
```

**Issue**

When compiling on MacOS, no problem occurs.

When compiling in rasbian however, I get `error: 'SIGINT' was not declared in this scope` error.

It is clear that `SIGINT` definition - `#define SIGINT 2` or similar - is not reachable when compiling on rasbian.

**Question**

Why I am getting this error on rasbian but not on macOS? Is it because compiler cannot locate `signal.h`?

I made sure that `include_directories` in CMakeLists.txt contains required include paths.

**UPDATE**

Error resolved when I manually added `#include <csignal>`.

Comment: `signal.h` is missing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't included signal.h.

You're including some C++ standard library headers, and as a side effect on MacOS, these happen to include signal.h. However, that isn't specified to happen so you can't rely on it working in different implementations of those headers.

Try adding:

```
#include <signal.h>
```

at the top.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it but still got the same error. However, error resolved when I included `<csignal>`. I would appreciate if anyone elaborates.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux the header file to include is

```
#include <signal.h>
```

On MacOS the equivalent header file to include is

```
#include <csignal.h>
```

Depending on your OS, header files always change. They should both do the same thing though